# MySQL Multiple Instances root user access denied

Tags: mysql

I have set up two instances of MySQL 8.0 on WSL2 in Windows 11 running Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the instructions for setup using systemd. I have verified that both servers are up and running on ports 3306 and 3307 respectively. I connected to the first instance correctly and it is running fine.

I am unable to connect to the second instance. Using

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3307 -u root
```

or

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -u root
```

The result is the same. If I try as above without password, I get the error message right away:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

If I add -p on the end, I get the error message after the Password prompt.

In troubleshooting, I went to the error log to look for the default password, and in the error log it says that the root user was created with empty password. I tried hitting enter at the password prompt and I tried entering a space. Same result.

I also tried adding "skip-grant-tables" at the bottom of the .cnf file with no change

Comment: Help me please everything I try has the same result. There is no way to get in as root and if you cannot get in as root you can do nothing. I can find NO answers that deal with this multi-instance context